# Webapp2: Get session value from BaseHandler method

Tags: google-app-engine, session, python-2.7, webapp2

I'm following webapp2 session documentation: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html .

`BaseHandler` have a class method `check_cls_login` here i need to check the session key "login" is exist or not. I tried `self.session.get("login")` but it returns error : `AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Also defined a function called `check_login` & it also return error: `AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'session_store'`

Base.py

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
       # Get a session store for this request.
       self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

       try:
         # Dispatch the request.
         webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
       finally:
         # Save all sessions.
         self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
       # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
       return self.session_store.get_session()

    def check_cls_login(self):
        # Check whether session key "login" is exist or not
        value = self.session.get("login")

def check_login(cls):
    # Check whether session key "login" is exist or not
    value = cls.session.get("login")
```

Main.py

```
from Base import BaseHandler

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
   def __init__(self, request, response):
    super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
    BaseHandler.check_cls_login() # AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'get'

    self.check_cls_login() # AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'get'

    check_login(self) # AttributeError: 'MainHandler' object has no attribute 'session_store'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `BaseHandler.check_login()` you should have `self.check_login()`.
And check_login shouldn't be a classmethod.

Comment: Same Error: `AttributeError: 'cached_property' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: check_login isn't a class method. Decorated as such, i'd guess that calling self.check_login() is the same as calling BaseHandler.check_login()

Comment: (Edited to expand on what I meant ... having a classmethod with 'self' as a parameter isn't usual in python code and it threw me, it would normally be 'cls')

Comment: Ah, I should pay more attention. Dispatch happens after init, so your sessions haven't been set up at that point. Overriding init in a handler is unusual, you'll need to incorporate it into dispatch, most likely.